# Accessing permissions in phpMyAdmin on a web hosting service

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a website with a database inside it using 000webhost.com. Now, I am trying to post 2 queries: one to add fields and one to retrieve all data from the database.  I already have the first query (to add), but when I try to make the second, I am getting the following error:

> **Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'a7172693'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/a7172693/public_html/retrieve.php** on line **11**

My PHP code for the query is as follows (secret info are replaced by hyphens):

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/JSON');

$mysqli = new mysqli('---------------------', '-------------', '--------', '-------------');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TableName');

echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
?>
```

Now, this code is supposed to just return an array containing all of the fields and all that stuff, but it's giving me that warning above.

If anyone could just give me a clue on what's wrong here, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mysqli as a database driver and then trying to query your database with mysql. change your code to this

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/JSON');
/* open connection*/
$connection = new mysqli_connect('---------------------', '-------------', '--------', '-------------');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
$json_array = array ();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json_array = $row;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```